# Will my circuit interfere with ATtiny25 in system programming?

Tags: attiny, isp

I've got a simple circuit with an ATtiny25 on which I indend to do in system programming. I'm wondering, will the rest of my circuit interfere with the SPI programming?

[image: Circuit]

So the data sheet says:

- PB0 = MOSI, this is used as an output so should be fine
- PB1 = MISO, this is used as an output so should be fine
- PB2 = SCK, this is used an input, connected to a voltage divider. So the 442 ohm resistor will cause a 7.4/11.3 mA current at 3.3/5 V, respectively.

Am I screwed here, is that too much?

Edit: I'm planning to use the Atmel-ICE programmer, but can't find any docs on how much current that can source.

Comment: As long as you're not messing with the reset pin you should be fine. And 7.4/11.3 mA is _nothing_. You should be looking over your shoulder if the programmer needs to give 100 mA.

Comment: @HarrySvensson That's good to hear. I looked up the SPI specs and all currents in that are in the µA range, that's what made me worried. But I suppose chip-to-chip SPI is different from ISP SPI.

Comment: @HarrySvensson So what would be considered as "messing with the reset pin"? Is my 1k resistor from vcc to reset fine?

Comment: That's just a regular pull-up that's usually on the reset pin, a little bit strong (10k would suffice), If you would've used anything less than 100 ohm's it would be within the range of "messing around".

Answer (score 3):

> is that too much?

no. i have done worse.

Comment: Excellent. Doesn't matter that it's a clock line?